# How do I install Roccat Vulcan 100 keyboard driver for light effects?

Tags: sudo, drivers, keyboard, make, keyboard-backlight

[Here's the driver (it is called a "driver", isn't it?) for keyboard backlight](https://github.com/duncanthrax/roccat-vulcan).

I'm mostly interested in playing with the source code to understand something more about drivers, if possible.

However, before diving into the code, I'd like to install it and see it working. That way I could really loop on "edit-reinstall-try" to see what effect my changes have.

Well, I'm blocked at square 1, as I haven't been able to install the driver.

To be honest, I haven't tried running `sudo make install`, and before doing so, I'd like to understand whether I truly need it and, if I do need it, understand why.

I see that the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/duncanthrax/roccat-vulcan/blob/master/src/Makefile) has this `install` target:

```
install:
    mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${BINDIR}
    cp $(NAME) ${DESTDIR}${BINDIR}/
    mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${UDEVDIR}
    cp *.rules ${DESTDIR}${UDEVDIR}/
```

and a few lines above there's

```
BINDIR  := /usr/bin
```

so it's clear to me that `sudo` privileges are required because `DESTDIR` is not set, so `${DESTDIR}${BINDIR}` resolves to `/usr/bin`, which needs `sudo` to be written to.

However, if there's a `${DESTDIR}` prefix in the first place, I wonder why I shouldn't run `make install DESTDIR=$HOME` or something.

Indeed, I tried, but the executable, `roccat-vulcan`, when run, errors with `Unable to find keyboard`. Maybe it does need to be installed in `/usr/bin`?

---

[A related question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25715/why-do-some-packages-use-make-install-while-other-use-sudo-make-install)

---

**Update**

As suggested in the answer, I've tried installing with `sudo make install BINDIR='/usr/local/bin'`, which succeed with the following ***output***:

```bsh
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
cp roccat-vulcan /usr/local/bin/
mkdir -p /etc/udev/rules.d
cp *.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

However, trying to run the software gives error. Below the output of `roccat-vulcan -v`:

```
ROCCAT Vulcan for Linux [github.com/duncanthrax/roccat-vulcan]
Effect Color Table (change these with -c option)
colorIdx    R      G      B  Desc
------------------------------------------------
0           0      0    119  Base keyboard color (dark blue)
1        2303      0   -255  Typing color, initial key (over-red, under-blue)
2        2303      0   -143  Typing color, first neighbor key
3        2303      0      0  Typing color, second neighbor key
4         187      0    204  Ghost typing color, initial key
5         153      0    187  Ghost typing color, first neighbor key
6          85      0    170  Ghost typing color, second neighbor key
7           0      0      0  (null)
8           0      0      0  (null)
9           0      0      0  (null)
open_device(1e7d, 3098): No LED device found
open_device(1e7d, 307a): ignoring non-LED interface #0
open_device(1e7d, 307a): ignoring non-LED interface #1
open_device(1e7d, 307a): ignoring non-LED interface #2
open_device(1e7d, 307a): LED interface at USB path 1-3:1.3
open_device(1e7d, 307a): Unable to open LED interface 1-3:1.3
Error: Unable to find keyboard
```

Comment: The page you linked says "Replug keyboard or reboot unless you want to run as root." I assume you did that? The build instructions also don't mention needing to run `sudo make install`.

Comment: Did you try the other steps listed there, such as running `lsusb` and comparing the ID?

Comment: @Panki, yes, I've unplugged and replugged the keyboard. As well as rebooted the system. Nothing worked. Yes, the instructions don't mention needing to run `sudo make install`, that's why I'm asking this question. As regards `lsusb`, for me the line of the keyboard is `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1e7d:307a ROCCAT ROCCAT Vulcan 100 AIMO`, whereas the repo has `Bus 001 Device 035: ID 1e7d:307a ROCCAT`. I guess the difference is irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

`${DESTDIR}${UDEVDIR}` doesn't resolve to /usr/bin, `${BINDIR}` does. `${DESTDIR}` is used for debugging installs. When it isn't specified, programs are installed in root of your filesystem or the `/` path. You have to run the program without setting `${DESTDIR}` for installing programs into your system.

Also, if you want to install the binaries in a different location, you have to set `BINDIR` to a directory which you own, like a directory in your $HOME folder. The freedesktop guys use $HOME/.local/bin/ and you can too. You can also add $HOME/.local/bin/ to your PATH variable so that you can use the executables without needing to specify their full path.

Lastly, according to the README of the linked project, if you want to run the program as non-root you need to be a member of the plugdev group. You can check if you are part of plugdev using `id -Gn <your username here>` and check if plugdev is listed. If you aren't in plugdev, you can add yourself to the group using `usermod -a -G plugdev <your username>`. Unfortunately you need root to add a user to a group, but after that you shouldn't require any more root access.

EDIT: Also, since your /etc/udev/rules.d directory is not writable by you, sudo will be needed for make install.

Comment: There was a typo in my question, which I've just corrected. Anyway, you write _You have to run the program without setting ${DESTDIR}_; are you telling me I should indeed run `sudo make install`?

Comment: I have updated the answer with full instructions on how to install your program.

Comment: This can't work without `sudo`, as the 3rd and 4th commands for `make install` try to act in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, as you can see at the linked [`Makefile`](https://github.com/duncanthrax/roccat-vulcan/blob/master/src/Makefile).

Comment: `useradd -a -G plugdev <my username>` fails with `invalid option -- 'a'`. By the way, `plugdev` group doesn't seem to exist, as `cat /etc/group  | grep plug` gives no output.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that you'll need superuser for executing `make`. However, since you're installing it using the makefile and not through the package manager, set BINDIR to '/usr/local/bin`. Also, without plugdev, superuser might also be required for running the program.

Comment: @Enlico It's actually `usermod`, there was a typo in my answer, but since plugdev doesn't exist, there's no point of creating it as usually udev access control is handled by the distro itself.

Comment: I've updated the question (adapted the title to what I'm really trying to do), and added the error I get now.

Comment: @Enlico As per the the project README `Replug keyboard or reboot unless you want to run as root.`. After installing you must do that before running the program

Comment: Yeah, I have done it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Enlico I was going off the on the wrong limb in the comments. The answer is right. [Take a look at this udev rules file in the source code](https://github.com/duncanthrax/roccat-vulcan/blob/5d2e389a0d910ae4af4195585dec918e4f3bc5a2/src/99-roccat-vulcan.rules). You can either create plugdev and add your user to plugdev. Or, if your system uses some other group for providing access to usb devices like `usb`, you can add your user to that group and edit the source of 99-roccat-vulcan.rules replacing `plugdev` at the end with the group name

Comment: I've done `groupadd plugdev`, `gpasswd -a myusername plugdev` and the message `Error: Unable to find keyboard` persists. I've also tried unistall (`rm` the stuff created when installing) and re-install again, but nothing changed.

Comment: Again, referring to the README, `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` must be run. Run that command, then replug the keyboard, and run the actual program.

Comment: Same failure. (Yes, I've used `sudo` for both commands you just suggested.)